# CSS First-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

"Set any content id-labelled element with a first-child descendant element of any of h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 as follows:"

The selector I've created is found below:

```
#content:first-child h1,
#content:first-child h2, 
#content:first-child h3, 
#content:first-child h4, 
#content:first-child h5, 
#content:first-child h6 {}
```

Is this correct? and if so can it be further simplified?

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: What is `:first-child` applying to in what you have written? What is it meant to apply to?

Comment: @Ischin: `:first-child` wasn't introduced in CSS3, it's been around since CSS2.

Comment: @Chris "a first-child descendant element of any of h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6"

Comment: @BoltClock: I wrote that to try to get @ChickSentMeHighE to think about it and see what was wrong with what he had put, rather than just giving the answer (especially as it's tagged "homework").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description is a little but unclear, but, from what I can understand you want to either

- select those h* elements and then the style would be like:

  ```
  #content h1:first-child,
  #content h2:first-child, 
  #content h3:first-child, 
  #content h4:first-child, 
  #content h5:first-child, 
  #content h6:first-child {}
  ```

[Example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0m)

- select the #container element itself in case the first child of it is one of h* family. Then you can not achieve this with pure CSS and need to add a simple JS like (using jQuery in this case):

  ```
  $('#content').has('h1:first-child, h2:first-child, h3:first-child, h4:first-child, h5:first-child, h6:first-child');
  ```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/GVeBj/)

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much it. Either way, the `:*-child` pseudo-classes should be attached to the children rather than the parents.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `class="header"` to all of your h* tags. So your css now would be

```
#content:first-child .header { /* whatever */ }
```

The problem here is that you need to remember to put the `class="header"` to every tag you need